# How to make android native shared library(.so) to be unable to debug by attaching

Tags: android

I am making the native shared library to be running on android.
Before, I experienced that protecting the shared library from debug(i.e set break point and trace) by attaching by IDA, at that time, SIGSTOP signal occurred and process was terminated.
So I wanna to make my library such that.
I will be appreciate to tell me how to.
Also, if you know another method to protect the native shared library to be running on android device from debug, disassemble or reverse-engineering.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can relatively easily detect a JVM debugger but detecting a native debugger is a bit harder.

You can use the [standard `ptrace(PTRACE_ME)` call](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/detecting-tracing-in-linux) to figure out if someone's attached a debugger. I've not tried this but I believe it should work.

Personally, I would use my own code-signing to figure out the state of the application, coupled with [support from Play Services](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html).

In any case, as with all things software, given enough patience all security measures can be circumvented.

Comment: Isn't there any method to do this in building phase not programming phase?

Comment: You can obfuscate the native code automatically but you can't prevent a debugger from being attached since that check has to go in specific places as otherwise it would severely affect performance.